# How to best deal with cracks in concrete?

Tags: concrete

My backyard has cracks in the concrete. The previous owners used concrete crack sealant/filler and that has eroded away or peeled away.

[image: cracks in concrete]

The options that I’m considering are:
(1) use filler again (this time a better kind, if available) but aesthetically it will looks like concrete with filled cracks. This is the most economic solution
(2) demo the existing concrete and pour a new slab
(3) pour a thin layer over the existing(I don’t even know if this is a good solution...it might just crack like a thin layer of ice.)

What is the best long term solution? I’m thinking of option (2). What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: If the existing concrete is stable, it could serve as a base for concrete or brick pavers.

Comment: I would coat with a polymer concrete, like they use in skate parks for a smooth finish that resist cracking.

Comment: @dandavis - do you mean on top of the existing cracked concrete?

Comment: yup, even with the more expensive mix, you'll be using a lot less to coat instead of replace, so it should be cheaper and maybe more durable, unless a whole replacement job is done perfectly, which will be quite expensive. You might also consider hotmix, treated to look like concrete or something else entirely, like a tennis court's surface for example; you don't have to go green, but it sure doesn't have to look like asphalt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacement is the most expensive but best solution. Be sure the base is properly prepared and compacted, and use reenforcing steel, which I have to suspect the current installation either did not, or not nearly enough. Steel is very inexpensive in the overall cost of having concrete poured, but adds a huge amount of strength to the result.

It also seems doubtful that "control joints" (neat, tidy, straight grooves in the concrete to encourage any cracks that DO form to form "just there") were made in the slab we are looking at. Those typically want to be no more than 12 feet / 4 meters apart.

Topping will soon crack in the same places, as the chunks of cracked concrete under it will continue to move relative to each other. Only if the topping was thick enough to sustain reenforcing steel of it's own might it hold up, and at that point you might as well go the sure route of replacement.

Sealing the cracks is a stopgap. Again, the chunks are now moving (slowly, for the most part, with the seasons) with respect to each other, so it's expected that the sealant will crack (if hard) or tear open (if flexible) eventually. On the other hand, as long as you can stand it, it's by far the least expensive solution.

Comment: +1 for recommending reinforcing steel...not mesh.

Comment: If you do install rebar you want it placed in a grid with all the cross intersections wire tied. It also has to be ensured that the rebar grid is positioned in the centerline of the pour thickness. All to often it gets left lying on the sand/gravel at the bottom of the slab where it does not help much.